# Shortest distance between two objects

Tags: vectors, 3d

Two objects $O_1$ and $O_2$ move in parallel according to the vectors $\vec{v_1}$, and $\vec{v_2}$. Determine the shortest distance in which objects will be and the time $t$ after which it will occur.

How I can solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081301/shortest-distance-between-two-vectors/3081637#3081637

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shortest distance between two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081301/shortest-distance-between-two-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{u_1}$ and $\vec{u_2}$ be the starting positions of the two objects.
If the two objects move in parallel, $\vec{v_2} = k\vec{v_1}$.
Hence the positions $\vec{x}$ of each object after time $t$ will be as follows:
$$\vec{x_1}=\vec{u_1}+t\vec{v_1}$$
$$\vec{x_2}=\vec{u_2}+kt\vec{v_1}$$
The distance of the two objects is 
$$d=|\vec{u_1}-\vec{u_2}+t(1-k)\vec{v_1}|$$
Now you can find the minimum of $d$ to find the shortest distance between the objects.